# while(!feof(file)) reading extra line

Tags: c, file-io

Im having an issue reading in lines from a file. Basically my code is reading in one extra line than it should with all variables being '0'i.e.

If my file is:

```
0, 0, 3, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0
2, 0, 6, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0
4, 0, 4, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0
6, 0, 5, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0
8, 0, 2, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

it will read in:

```
Object 1:  0, 0, 3, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0
Object 2:  2, 0, 6, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0
Object 3:  4, 0, 4, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0
Object 4:  6, 0, 5, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0
Object 5:  8, 0, 2, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0
Object 6:  0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Here is my read algorithm:

```
while (!feof(pfile)) { 

        PcbPtr p = createnullPcb();
        fscanf(pfile, "%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d", &p->arrivaltime, &p->priority, &p->remainingcputime, 
        &p->memalloc, &p->pr,  &p->sc, &p->mo, &p->cd);
        char cwd[1024];
        char *tmp = getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));
        strcat(tmp, "/process");
        p->args[0] = tmp;
        p->args[1] = NULL;

        if (!headi) {
            headi = p;
        } 
        else {
            enqPcb(&headi, p);
        }

    }
```

Why is this happening? Thanks for any help!

Comment: may be a new line (ENTER) is at the end of your input file

Comment: @MaziarBouali No i checked that, see below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's happening is that `feof` returns `true` when there was an attempt to read past the end. When you are at the end of your file, but haven't tried to read anything else yet, `feof` will return `false`.

In simple words: `feof` does not stand for *is at the end of the file*, but for *has attempted to access past the end of the file*.

Note that when you are at the end of the file and try to read that extra line, `fscanf` will fail. You could check its return value to see if it was able to read anything.

Comment: Oh ok thanks, so maybe something like: 
    if (!fscanf(pfile, "%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d", &p->arrivaltime,     &p->priority, &p->remainingcputime, 
      &p->memalloc, &p->pr,  &p->sc, &p->mo, &p->cd)){
       free(p)
       break;
      }

Comment: @Milk: That _may_ work, `fscanf` returns the number of matched arguments so you are checking to see if it didn't matched any argument at all. For commenting code in comments use backticks: `